# How to get download link to the file, in the firefox downloads via selenium and python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I can't get link in webpage, it's generat automaticly using JS. But I can get firefox download window after clicking on href (it's a JS script, that returns href).

How can I get the link in this window using selenium. If i can't do this, is there any other way to get link (no explicit link in the HTML DOM)

Comment: does the URL is static, if not you need to identify from which source you are getting the URL, if javascript you need to use javascriptexecutor, first do R&D on same or ask your dev', you need to share the URL if you need to help from here, without observing no one can predict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # 2 means custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp') # location is tmp
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get("yourwebsite")

element = browser.find_element_by_id('yourLocator')
href = element.get_attribute("href")
```

Now you have website in your href.

Use below code to navigate to the URL

```
browser.navigate().to(href)
```

Comment: This is how looks like my href attribute in HTML 
<a href=javascript:dnn('some_key_word') class=fn9>some_name.zip</a>

Comment: does this some_name.zip appending in your existing website? observe it or its just totally an another URL?

Comment: Yep, the final link looks like the random string, and i can't assum what link will be generate in random case.

Comment: check if that details feeding in your webpage by any API, if that the case you need to grab the api response

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the following approach:

1. Get WebElement's [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp) using [WebElement.get_attribute()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) function

   ```
   href = your_element.get_attribute("href")
   ```
2. Use [WebDriver.execute_script()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebDriver.execute_script) function to evaluate the JavaScript and return the real URL

   ```
   url = driver.execute_script("return " + href + ";")
   ```
3. Now you should be able to use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) or [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to download the file. If your website assumes authentication - don't forget to obtain [Cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) from the browser instance and add the relevant [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header to the request downloading the file

Comment: In my case, there no any normal href links on DOM. This is how my link looks like in html code 
 <a href=javascript:dnn('some_key_word') class=fn9>some_name.zip</a>